# how to merge records by latest value

Tags: sql-server, merge, subquery

I have this:

```
name time      val1 val2 val3
bill 12/1/2010 2    3    4
bill 12/2/2010 1         5
bill 11/1/2010 1    NULL 5

....
```

How can I end up with this:

```
name time      val1 val2 val3
bill 12/2/2010 1    3    5
```

In my case `name` is a unique value and is guaranteed to belong to the same person. I tried:

```
select * from table1 v1
INNER JOIN table1 v2 
ON t2.name = t1.name
GROUP BY t1.name;
```

But that doesnt address how to get the latest value. I would appreciate any suggestions with the thought process behind them- Im struggling to combine getting the 'latest' value by timestamp and the 'complete' value based on whether or not they answered the question.

Heres the T-SQL code to reproduce my (tiny) dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
    [name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [time] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [val1] [varchar](50),
    [val2] [varchar](50),
    [val3] [varchar](50),
)

GO

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('bill','12/1/2010','2','3','1');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('bill','12/2/2010','1','','5'); ---NO TEXT ENTERED
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('bill','11/1/2010','2',NULL,'1'); ---QUESTION NOT SEEN. PUTS NULL IN RESULT

GO
```

Comment: With such a data model proceed to denormalize it more - always keep the latest record somewhere else, in additional "true" table. The data shown should be treated as historical data.

Comment: Thanks, I will do some reading on how to do that!

Comment: You have enough rep around here to know that this is not a very good question. How about ddl and sample data in a consumable format?

Comment: @SeanLange You're correct, unfortunately Im very new to SQL and wasnt sure how to get an SQL question in the right format. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I will google DDL now

Comment: Here is a great article on how to collect this info. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for the tip, I updated my question. Let me know if there is anything else I can add!

Comment: That looks great. Do you really store these numbers as text? Of course I have to remove the primary key because you have the same value in every row. :)

Comment: Ugh...didn't notice you have dates stored as strings also. Which "format" is this stored in? In your real table I hope you have the proper datatype and not varchar.

Comment: Would you be able to change the data?  For example instead of '' and NULL could you use 0 and -1 and then just have the data type as int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest this is a lot harder than it needs to be because it seems your data is not well normalized. And then you are trying to get an even further denormalized result set. If the data was normalized correctly to start with this would be a lot easier. I had to fix your ddl (can't have a primary key with duplicates on name). And I also had to fix your sample data to match what you posted originally.

I am sure there are other ways to deal with this but here is what I came up with.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
    [name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [time] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [val1] [varchar](50),
    [val2] [varchar](50),
    [val3] [varchar](50),
)

GO

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('bill','12/1/2010','2','3','1');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('bill','12/2/2010','1','','5'); ---NO TEXT ENTERED
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('bill','11/1/2010','2',NULL,'1'); ---QUESTION NOT SEEN. PUTS NULL IN RESULT
;

with val1 as
(
    select name
        , val1
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by name order by time desc)
    from table1
    where val1 > ''
)
, val2 as
(
    select name
        , val2
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by name order by time desc)
    from table1
    where val2 > ''
)
, val3 as
(
    select name
        , val3
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by name order by time desc)
    from table1
    where val3 > ''
)

select t.name
    , max(t.time)
    , val1 = max(v1.val1)
    , val2 = max(v2.val2)
    , val3 = max(v3.val3)
from table1 t
left join val1 v1 on v1.name = t.name and v1.RowNum = 1
left join val2 v2 on v2.name = t.name and v2.RowNum = 1
left join val3 v3 on v3.name = t.name and v3.RowNum = 1
group by t.name
```